# Install SSL Certificate - Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine

I am trying to install my SSL Certificate Issued by GoDaddy to my Google Compute Engine VM.(Debian8, Apache Server)

But I am getting the following Error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.name': 'SSL_CERTIFICATE'. Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)'
```

The Steps I followed were(on my local machine):

```
mkdir ssl_cert
cd ssl_cert
openssl genrsa -out example.key 2048
openssl req -new -key example.key -out example.csr
```

Ref Link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates

These 4 commands created an example.csr & example.key files inside ssl_cert.
I then went to godaddy.com & pasted the contents of example.csr and downloaded a example.com.zip file(corresponding to 'Others' Server) which contained 2 .crt files: file1.crt & file2.crt

I then tried:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create SSL_CERTIFICATE --certificate file1.crt --private-key example.key
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create SSL_CERTIFICATE --certificate file2.crt --private-key example.key
```

But got the same error for both of these commands.

Can someone please explain how can I install it correctly?

Comment: Any Suggestions please ?

Answer (score 3):

In your commands

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create **SSL_CERTIFICATE** --certificate file1.crt --private-key example.key
```

and

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create **SSL_CERTIFICATE** --certificate file2.crt --private-key example.key
```

Change the name of the certificate you are creating using above commands from `SSL_CERTIFICATE` to `somesimplename` only with the help of the regex specified in your error message.

Underscore `_` can not be used as it is not specified in the regex

Here is the example :

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create sslcertificate1 --certificate file1.crt --private-key example.key
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create sslcertificate2 --certificate file2.crt --private-key example.key
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to provide HTTPS service through a 3rd party software (e.g., Apache HTTP Server), `gcloud compute ssl-certificates` is not for your use case. It's for adding SSL certificate to the managed GCE HTTPS Load Balancer.

Just install SSL certificate by following the instructions of Apache HTTP Server, it's transparent to GCE, as it works at layer 3 in your case.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference link if possible ? I tried following this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04 but it didn't worked out..

Comment: (Instead of self - signed, I obtained certificate from GoDaddy using .csr file)